# How do you use tqdm when skipping iterations that were completed during a previous run (time remaining being incorrect)?

Tags: python, tqdm

My current program is designed to keep checkpoints of its progress and then skip the completed parts if it is later rerun after some interruption. I am using `tqdm` to show the progress of the program but when skipping iterations the estimated time remaining shown becomes under-estimated because `tqdm` thinks that the skipped parts were completed instead of skipped.

Is there a way to display the total number of iterations but signal that an iteration was skipped rather than completed? Basically I would like the progress bar to start out partially loaded but have the estimated time remaining showing how long it will take to complete the remaining iterations only.

PS I will consider using another progress bar instead of `tqdm` if there is one that supports this feature.

Comment: Hi, have you ever figured this out?

Comment: If you really need it, what I would do is to slightly refactor the code so you pre-compute the iterations you still have to process before the loop, and then only loop through these ones (i.e. the ones you don't have the checkpoints of yet).

Answer (score 1):

tqdm has a parameter `initial` that you can use to specify where the progress bar should start. It does mean that you have to figure out how many iterations were skipped in advance, but otherwise should do what you want.